# Project`s dlls missing after publish asp .net web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, publish

I have updated my Visual Studio 2017 two weeks ago, but I found the Project`s dll's are missing after publishing my asp .net web project. I remember it was always there before. So I want to know if this is an expected behavior or a issue?

Besides, publish type is file system publish.

Update:

Below is my Publish Profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>bin\Release\PublishOutput</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

I`m a new user for SO, if I have any incorrect operation, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid you're gonna have to share more information about your publish profile and project that you're publishing. Have you checked your bin folder if the dll is there or not?

Comment: Do not easily deny others. I have said I`m new to SO. And this issue should easy to reproduced, the publish profile is very common. Have you ever test this issue before you vote down it? @sunilsachdeva, I have updated my question with publish profile and I`m make sure the project`s dll is missing from my bin folder.

Comment: Where did you check or validate on your local system where the missing dll's are at? Second how did you come to notice that the dll's are missing?

Comment: @aaronR, the missing project`s dll is in the bin folder. When you build you project, you must notice that the project dll at bin folder after build, but if you publish this project, that dll will be "delete".

Comment: Did you see them in the bin\Release or bin\debug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So I want to know if this is an expected behavior or a issue?

I have encountered the similar issue on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/984a4153-387c-4fb1-97db-c1e73ba0a042/visual-studio-153-publish-deletes-dlls-in-other-projects?forum=msbuild). I could reproduce this issue as you description on the **Visual Studio 2017 15.3.0** and later.

When we build the ASP.NET web project, for example, the project name is `WebApplicationTest`, after build this project. The `WebApplicationTest.dll` will generated at `WebApplicationTest\bin` folder.

However, this WebApplicationTest.dll will be deleted after you publish this web project. I test this on the previous version 15.2 and Visual Studio 2015, it works fine, that dll file still exists after publish.

[image]

So I have already submit this issue to the Visual Studio Developer Community (This issue is still under investigation), you can follow with your comments and check the feedback of this issue.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/96746/visual-studio-153-publish-aspnet-web-projects-will.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that`s my question. It seems I need wait for Developer Community feedback.

Comment: Any problem reported in community 2019?