# Visual Studio Build deletes website application from ignored project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am experiencing a bizarre build problem.

This problem was introduced after I upgraded Visual Studio 2017 from version 15.2 to 15.3.

There are three build configurations:

- ServerDeployment|Any CPU
- ServerDeployment|x86
- MediaPlayerDeployment|x86

My automated build builds the three configurations in order, using a command line like this:

```
devenv OurSolutionFile.sln /rebuild "ServerDeployment|Any CPU"
devenv OurSolutionFile.sln /rebuild "ServerDeployment|x86"
devenv OurSolutionFile.sln /rebuild "MediaPlayerDeployment|x86"
```

The first configuration includes a WebApplication. It builds to a file called 'CMS.Website.dll'.
The second configuration (ServerDeployment|x86) is configured to NOT BUILD this application.

What's happening is that the first build command creates it, but then the second build command **deletes it again!**.

It's not performing a clean: the rest of the folder `CMS.Website\bin` remains. It just surgically removes the file `CMS.Website\bin\CMS.Website.dll`.

Why is this happning?

How can I stop it happening?

---

I looked at the build output of the `ServerDeployment|x86` build. The only mention of CMS.Website.dll is the following two lines:

> 37>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: CMS.Website, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
>
> 37>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration

Comment: I've duplicated this question in the Visual Studio Developer Community forum: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/127779/visual-studio-build-deletes-website-application-fr.html

Comment: It seems like a issue for Visual Studio 2017 15.3 and above. I have the similar issue when publish web application project and I also submit it on developer community: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087918/projects-dlls-missing-after-publish-asp-net-web-project/46088893#46088893

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was recognized as a defect by Microsoft, and a fix was added to Visual Studio 15.5, preview 2 (as of 25 October, 2017).

See [this conversation](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/127779/visual-studio-build-deletes-website-application-fr.html)

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.